# How to limit console input

Tags: c#

I am trying to check user input which supposes to be a four-digit account number only. if the user enters more or less input. it would say "invalid entry". I am not sure how to check var length in c#.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a four-digit account number");
        int acc = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int d = acc % 10; 
        acc = acc / 10; 
        if (acc % 7 == d)
            Console.WriteLine("Valid Account Number");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Account Number");
```

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` returns a string.  A string has a `Length` property.

Comment: Side note, you may want to look into `int.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32` for better error handling.

Comment: A 4 digits integer number is a number between 1000 and 9999.

Comment: You might also want to look into `Console.ReadKey()`, which will detect individual keys pressed, then you can just give more immediate feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Updated

```
var inputText = Console.ReadLine();
var inputNumber = 0;
// try to parse - if success, then parsingFlag = True
// and parsed number is stored to inputNumber
var parsingFlag = Int32.TryParse(inputText, out inputNumber);
if ((inputNumber >= 1000) && (inputNumber <= 9999))
{
    // do your algorithm
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry");
```

Comment: Can you please explain in brief?

Comment: Updated, added comments

Comment: Thanks @Steve, updated the answer. Actually, if we care just about 4 digit numbers, so the easiest would be to check if we are in range.